# How To Correctly Center Alignt a Banner Slider in Magento?

Tags: css, magento, slider, banner

I'm trying to center align a banner slider, but it's not centering correctly. It center only on my screen if I change the margin-left attribute to match my screens resolutions. But it doesn't get centered on wider screens. My website is myusedwheel.com and this is the code I have for it:

```
<style type="text/css">
#slider{
    margin-left: 195px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 192px;
    width:960px!important;
    height:173px !important;
 }

#navigation{
    position:relative; z-index:999;
 }

 .header-container{
    height:385px;
 }

#controls{
    display:none;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no reason for you to be using absolute positioning on your slider.  If you moved your slider to the top in your code hierachy, it would sit fine above the content.

With that being said, to fix it with your current code structure, you can do the following.

1. Add `position: relative` to `.page` on `line 200` in your `styles.css`
2. Change `margin-left` to `20px` for `#slider`

This should correctly position your slider in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the slider with something like `<div class='slide-container'>` and use:

```
.slide-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -600px;
}
```

There are times when `margin: 0 auto;` is sufficient, but I've found that using `left: 50%;` with a negative left margin equal to half the element's width works best.